# ST_Subdivide only returning a single polygon when given a valid polygon as input

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am trying to **divide the bounding box of a country into smaller 1km square polygons** to be able to speed up my queries against millions of points (get all polygons within a radius of a selection then only query against points that are within those polygons)

**I am using the following query** to divide the bounding_box of the country but I only get 1 row returned from this query

```
SELECT (ST_Subdivide(bounding_box, 1000)) FROM ref_countries WHERE name = 'United Kingdom';
```

When I expected many rows of smaller polygons

**I have checked that the geometry type is a polygon using:**

```
SELECT ST_GeometryType(bounding_box) FROM ref_countries WHERE name = 'United Kingdom'
```

*which returns "ST_Polygon"*

**I have also checked that the geometry is valid using:**

```
SELECT ST_IsValid(bounding_box) FROM ref_countries WHERE name = 'United Kingdom'
```

*which return "true"*

I have also tried using **ST_DUMP** (ST_Dump(ST_Subdivide(bounding_box, 10000))).geom as this seemed to be a possible soultion, but still no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`ST_Subdivide`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Subdivide.html) "brakes" a **big** polygon into several smaller, irregular, ones. In your code, you instruct that each smaller polygon could have up to 1000 vertices. Since you are feeding it with a bounding box, so 4 vertices, the source polygon is way below the vertices threshold and is therefore returned untouched.

You may instead want to use [`ST_SquareGrid`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_SquareGrid.html) to create a regular grid within the specified bounds.

Answer (score 1):

The concept of subdividing is to reduce *vertex counts* - a bounding box is by definition the least complex *Polygon* with 4 corners and 5 vertices with no further optimization possible.

You want to `ST_SubDivide` the actual country *Polygon* instead. PostGIS' `GIST` index implementation will then use the bounding boxes of each subdivision for candidate lookups.

---

That being said, a highly efficient polygon gridding approach for PIP queries is not directly implemented in PostGIS.